# CLion on Mac - how to reference /Library/Frameworks?

Tags: macos, clion, gstreamer-1.0

I'm using CLion 2019.2 on a mac running macOS 10.14.6. Trying to get a GStreamer basic tutorial C program to run that runs on my linux box. All XCode preqs and commandline tools are installed too. Think I have all the correct include files in CMakelists.txt.

How do I setup CLion to be sure it includes the necessary Gstreamer.framework?

And how do I include the right cmake compile options? Gstreamer info suggests the info below but not sure where to put it in Preferences->Build, Execution, Deployment->CMake - Build option or CMake options?

**Thanks for helping a noob**. Info from GSstreamer for mac page:

** The GStreamer binaries provides a framework that you can drag and drop to XCode to start using it, or using the linker option -framework GStreamer*.*

** There is a small exception to the regular use of frameworks, and you will need to manually include the headers search path /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers

** XCode: Add the headers path to Search Paths → Header Search Paths
GCC: Using the compiler option -I/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Headers